# How to find a file in a subdirectory and immediately open it - Terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

trying to make my workflow more efficient. I often have two files of the same name in two directories held within one "master" directory like this:

root

- folder_1
- - my_website.html
- folder_2
- - my_website.html

From within terminal I can enter:

```
find -L . -name "my_website.html"
```

and that gives me the list of files and their locations. But I'd like to open them directly from here, rather than navigate down the directories. Is there a way to chain an open command on to open both of the files it finds.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably better suited for forums such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What do you mean by "open"?  Perhaps you just want `vi $(find ...)`

Comment: by open I mean view in browser - most of the files I'm looking at are html.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and toying I came across this which works:

```
find -L . -name 'my_website.html' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 open
```